# Recieving both eventType and notificationType from Amazon SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I have configured Amazon SNS event publishing to get email's Open, Click, Bounce, Complaint events.

[In documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/event-publishing-retrieving-sns-contents.html#event-publishing-retrieving-sns-contents-top-level-json-object) Amazon says after setting it up I will get a JSON object with `eventType` and other fields.

Problem is that I am getting both `event` and `notification` JSON objects to the same endpoint that I have configured for event publishing.

There are 2 requests coming to my configured endpoint

- eventType-Bounce
- notificationType-Bounce

Example for `eventType-Bounce`:

```json
{
   "Type":"Notification",
   "MessageId":"someMessageID",
   "TopicArn":"arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:someId:ses-bounces-topic",
   "Subject":"Amazon SES Email Event Notification",
   "Message":"{\"eventType\":\"Bounce\",\"bounce\".......
```

Example for `notificationType-Bounce`:

```json
{
    "Type": "Notification",
    "MessageId": "someMessageID",
    "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:someId:ses-bounces-topic",
    "Message": "{\"notificationType\":\"Bounce\",\"bounce\".......
```

`MessageId` is same for both objects which means it is sending 2 event for 1 email.

In Documentation it says `eventType` can be named as `notificationType` if you didn't set up event publishing which I did:

[image]